# Configure log4net for asp.net MVC3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, log4net

Ok, so I'm understood how to configure the `log4Net` in my application, But now

**First** I want to improve the configuration by differencing the level of the logs if the application it's a release or a debug, how can I do this?.

**Second**, If I had a folder in my project called `LOG` how can I set the configuration, to not used the physical folder of my application??

**for example Instead of:**

```
<file value="C:\physicalpath\LOG\Log.log" />
```

**used**

```
<file value="\LOG\Log.log" />
```

or

```
<file value="%some_variable%\LOG\Log.log" />
```

Comment: If you're logging to a folder within your application, be aware that an attacker could view the contents of this folder with a little guesswork & view sensitive information about your app. Either make the folder non-viewable in IIS manager (remove read permission), or put the folder outside the web root.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The documenation is straight forward:

> **file**: the full or relative path to the log file.

So all you need to have is the full path like `C:\physicalpath\LOG\Log.log` or the ralative one, this needs to start with the **dot char** `.` like `.\App_Data\Log4Net.Logs`

you can also use the **folder name** in the `file` attribute, then you must use the `datePattern` attribute to specify the file name, for example:

```xml
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value=".\\App_Data\\Log4Net.Logs\\backend"/>
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="256KB"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

**Also remember** to add the

```xml
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
```

So you can avoid that `log4net` lock the file and you can't used it to append your messages.

If you're not used to `log4net`, don't forget to add the `<root>` node, this is the the one that let's `log4net` know what you want to use and not the `<appender>` nodes, for example, you can have 10 `<appender>` nodes and use only one, the `<root>` node is then only configured with the one you want to use...

---

here is a **full configuration** with 2 Mongo Appenders and 1 File Appender, the `<root>` specifies that only the file appender is in use:

```xml
  <log4net>
    <appender name="MongoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.MongoDBAppender, log4mongo-net">
      <!-- MongoDB 1 connection options -->
      <host value="staff.mongohq.com"/>
      <port value="10077"/>
      <databaseName value="myApp_2011"/>
      <collectionName value="logs_net"/>
      <userName value="myself"/>
      <password value="123456"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="MongoAppenderAppHarbor" type="log4net.Appender.MongoDBAppender, log4mongo-net">
      <!-- MongoDB 2 connection options -->
      <host value="staff.mongohq.com"/>
      <port value="10048"/>
      <databaseName value="d1741d63-46b1-4a44-9c49-8c28cecae36b"/>
      <collectionName value="logs_net"/>
      <userName value="myself"/>
      <password value="123456"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <!-- Local file options -->
      <file value=".\\App_Data\\Log4Net.Logs\\backend"/>
      <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="256KB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <!--
         <level value="DEBUG" />
         <appender-ref ref="MongoAppender" />
         <appender-ref ref="MongoAppenderAppHarbor" />
      -->
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for asking ok I understand clearly my doubt related to the physical paths, but your full configuration it's your recommendations for my first concern about the two configuration bot release and debug???. Thanks

Comment: no, no, it's my own live implementation (apart of the login data)... so, **there are 2 different questions** on your question. can you please **separate** them and post the new url here. Let this one be for "how to use relative path" and create a new one asking for how to use the different schemas...

Comment: and where's the new question?

Comment: it's the first one. Where i asked the how configured log4net for debug and release, and the second one asking for physical paths to output the loggers

Comment: What I have asked you, was to delete that question line and create a new question with that, so you will end us with 2 questions in StackOverflow... one per each real question, that's the forum rules ;)

Answer (score 4):

Remember maybe you should to add in Global.asax.cs the follow code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    //...more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample `app.config` section, with the Path being defined through the `<file value="somepath"/>` tag.

[This link](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) is a good resource for documentation

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <file value="C:\\SOMEPATH\\SOMELOG.log"/>
   <appendToFile value="true"/>
   <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
   <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger – %message%exception%newline"/>
   </layout>    
 </appender>
 <root>
   <level value="ALL"/>
   <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
 </root>      
</log4net>
```